# android Django rest API,authentication

Tags: android, django, api, rest

A friend have a Rest API with Django, and Im trying to make and android app for it, but I having problems with the authentication.

First i get the CSRF token, just making a get call and taking the value.

```
public String getCFSRToken() throws Exception{

    String csrftokenValue="";
    httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(urlBasic));
    cookieStore = httpClient.getCookieStore();
    List <Cookie> cookies =  cookieStore.getCookies();      
    for (Cookie cookie: cookies) {
        Log.v("csrftoken",cookie.getName());
        if ( cookie.getName().compareTo("csrftoken")==0) {
            csrftokenValue = cookie.getValue();
        }
    }
    return csrftokenValue;
}
```

Then I try to make the authentication:

```
public void login3() throws Exception{
    String urlLogin ="/login";
    String url = urlBasic+urlLogin;
    String username = "jesus.m.martinez.garcia";
    String password = "lolofree";
    String userpass = username +":"+password;       
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

//              List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
//              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
//              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
//              post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(userpass.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP ));
    post.addHeader("Authorization", basicAuth);

    post.addHeader("X-CSRFToken",  getCFSRToken());
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

    CookieStore as = httpClient.getCookieStore();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line = "";
    String pagina="";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
         pagina= pagina + "\n"+line;
     }
     System.out.println(pagina);
}
```

If I don't add the CSRF header I receive always a 403 Forbidden, so I suppose that part is correct, but when I try to do the login with the post (as you can see I have try without codification and basic), I always receive a 200 Ok, but I receive an HTML page for logging and I don't get the session cookie, that's what is killing me.

I asked my friend and he told me, he didn't modify the authentication of Django framework, so I suppose is not digest. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance ;)